# Generating and Optimizing Webp via Gulp

Tags: optimization, gulp, yeoman-generator, webp

I'm using the [generator webapp](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-webapp) which includes imagemin. I've also added [imagemin-webp](https://github.com/imagemin/imagemin-webp) and [gulp-webp](https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-webp) to my build.

I am unsure how to implement. I want to keep the original jpg and png images in addition to adding webp, and have all these images optimized when running `gulp build` task.

I am confused at [this stage](https://github.com/imagemin/imagemin-webp#imageminwebpoptions).

How do I implement it based on my current setup:

```
const webp = require('gulp-webp');
const imageminWebp = require('imagemin-webp');

gulp.task('images', () => {
    return gulp.src('app/images/**/*')
    .pipe(webp())
    .pipe($.cache($.imagemin()))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/images'));
});
```

Currently, this just generates unoptimized webp files and doesn't package any of the original jpg and png files.

Answer (score 3):

This is my option in 2021 year. If you have some question, just ask me.

```js
const {src, dest, parallel, series, watch} = require('gulp');
const imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin');
const webp = require('imagemin-webp');
const extReplace = require('gulp-ext-replace');

const exportWebP = () => {
  return src(['./src/img/**/*.jpg', './src/img/**/*.png'], {base: 'src'})
    .pipe(imagemin([
      webp({
        quality: 60,
      })
    ]))
    .pipe(extReplace('.webp'))
    .pipe(dest('./app/'))
}

watch(['./src/img/**/*.jpg', './src/img/**/*.png'], exportWebP);
exports.default = series(parallel(exportWebP));
```

Comment: "[ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() not supported" occurs because the gulp-imagemin package has been converted to be an ESM only package in version 8.0.0, which means that the package cannot be imported with require() anymore. So: downgrade the version of the gulp-imagemin package to 7.1.0  = npm install --save-dev gulp-imagemin@7.1.0

Answer (score 0):

You have to include [gulp-clone](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-clone) to output the original files with their webp counterparts. It would look something like this:

```
const webp = require('gulp-webp');
const imageminWebp = require('imagemin-webp');
const clone = require('gulp-clone');
const clonesink = clone.sink();

gulp.task('images', () => {
    return gulp
        .src('app/images/**/*')
        .pipe($.cache($.imagemin())) // optimize images before converting
        .pipe(clonesink) // start stream
        .pipe(webp()) // convert images to webp and save a copy of the original format
        .pipe(clonesink.tap()) // close stream and send both formats to dist
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/images'));
});
```

Comment: Hello @Morgan, it's been a long time since this has been commented, but that process works pretty good for me when I start gulp, but when my watch function catches new images I get this error `(node:16040) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: write after end`. It only happens on watch, when I start the process everything is generated correctly.